# LibCurl C Http Post/Get

Tags: c, perl, libcurl

I am converting a Perl program to C using libcurl

```
sub IsAdmin() {
    $r = &HTTPGet("http://".$_[0]."wp-admin/edit.php");
    if (!$r->is_success) { return FALSE; }
    if ($r->content =~ /wp-admin\/post.php\?/) {
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
 }
```

And this one

```
sub IsWordPress() {
    my $url = $_[0];
    $url =~ s/http:\/\///;
    my $new_url = "http://" . $url . "/wp-login.php";
    my $r = &HTTPGet($new_url);
    if ($r->content =~ /action=lostpassword/) {
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

My program will send an HTTP request and see if the response contains a specific string; for example `action=lostpassword`.

I want to send an HTTP POST request and get the base URL, regardless of redirections, and the contents of the response.

Comment: I have made major changes to your question. Please check what I have written and make sure that it describes your problem properly.

Comment: Please show the C code that you have written, and describe the problems  you are having in getting it to work.

Comment: @Borodin Thankyou but I don't think my question deserved down voting.I was just seeking help from you guys.Damn man learn to accept people in your community.I know you guys are way better programmer than I am.But Hi that is why I am asking for your help.Anyways Got the answer from somewhere else thanks for you help.

Comment: Neither of the two downvotes are mine. I was waiting for you to confirm that my edits were valid. Please remember that Stack Overflow isn't a forum and there is no “community”. Questions are judged according to their general relevance as well as the quality of their content. If you have a solution then you should post it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: My understanding is that per the code, OP is trying to send an `HTTP GET` (see use of `HTTPGet` in both source snippets). I don't know whether this is due to the edit, but it now says `HTTP POST` in the text below the code. It also suggests OP is trying to retrieve the URL itself rather than the data at the URL. It would be useful if this was made clear one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

`libcurl` provides a fantastic number of example bits of code [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html).

However, by far the best way quickly to generate C code that does what you want is to use the command line `curl` tool with the `--libcurl` option:

```
   --libcurl <file>
          Append this option to any ordinary curl command  line,  and  you
          will  get a libcurl-using C source code written to the file that
          does the equivalent of what your command-line operation does!

          If this option is used several times, the last given  file  name
          will be used. (Added in 7.16.1)
```

For instance the command:

```
curl --silent --libcurl /tmp/test.c http://www.google.com/
```

gives the output:

```
/********* Sample code generated by the curl command line tool **********
 * All curl_easy_setopt() options are documented at:
 * http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html
 ************************************************************************/
#include <curl/curl.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *hnd;

  hnd = curl_easy_init ();
  curl_easy_setopt (hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
  curl_easy_setopt (hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt (hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.35.0");
  curl_easy_setopt (hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
  curl_easy_setopt (hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  /* Here is a list of options the curl code used that cannot get generated
     as source easily. You may select to either not use them or implement
     them yourself.

     CURLOPT_WRITEDATA set to a objectpointer
     CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
     CURLOPT_READDATA set to a objectpointer
     CURLOPT_READFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
     CURLOPT_SEEKDATA set to a objectpointer
     CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
     CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER set to a objectpointer
     CURLOPT_STDERR set to a objectpointer
     CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
     CURLOPT_HEADERDATA set to a objectpointer

   */

  ret = curl_easy_perform (hnd);

  curl_easy_cleanup (hnd);
  hnd = NULL;

  return (int) ret;
}

/**** End of sample code ****/
```

Comment: OK, so given the *original* question, why did that deserve a downvote?

Comment: Please explain. How is your solution pertinent to the original post but irrelevant to the edit?

Comment: @Borodin: I can't now see the original, but it wasn't a model of clarity but appeared to be asking how one produced a C program to download a URL in the same way as some perl. In general the advice *'make it work with `curl` and add `--libcurl`'* is pretty useful for that. The question appears now to have been changed to be much more specific (re `POST`, no redirections etc.), but again, if you can do that with `curl` on the command line, the `--libcurl` directive will translate that into C. I don't think it's reasonable to penalise an answerer for an unclear question.

Comment: The edit to the question was mine, and I asked in a comment for the OP to check that it was correct. You will receive many downvotes, and a lot of them will seem to be unfair. This one was mine, and it was because your answer doesn't address the specific Perl code that the OP asked to be translated. I think the question is still unclear, but it is wrong to guess at its meaning and offer an answer to that guess: you should ask questions to clarify the problem and offer an answer only when you are sure what you are answering.